# Global variables in node only for specific users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In node, I have a global.js files with an object, for example:

```
var global = {
  TEST_ENV: {
    enabled: true
  },


  user: {
    userID: null,
    name: null,
    email: null,
  },

  db: null,

  socket: null
};

module.exports = global;
```

I then set the properties (that are null) to some values (in some route) and I require that global file wherever I need to use the global variables.

This is good for the properties such as TEST_ENV, and db which never change. However for the user object, I see that when I update the object, it overwrites for all users (if I console log global.user at the next connected user, it logs the previous user's properties).

What's a good way to keep a global var / object to only this connected user? So for instance the next users who connected to my app, see a user object with null properties and not the properties that were set by the previous user.

Thanks

Comment: push a new user object for each person that connects. Each use should have their own object.

Comment: ...or use [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session?_ga=1.151649145.1795931354.1444833875) for users instead of global variables .

Comment: Agree with @Nocturno.  You want to use sessions.  This creates state for each separate user.  There are many node.js modules that provide support for sessions which generally use a client cookie as a key into a local store to get to a given user's state at any time.